# Xamarin Android Emulator Manager doesn't show all platforms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have latest Visual Studio 2017 15.6.7, Xamarin Android Device Manager installed and:

- Android SDK Tools           26.1.1
- Android SDK Platform-Tools  27.0.1
- Android SDK Build-Tools     27.0.3

[image]

- Android Emulator            27.1.12

[image]

In Xamarin Android Emulator Manager, when trying to create a new image, it doesn't show system image for Android 6, although I have it installed

[image]

[image]

How to make the Xamarin Android Device Manager see Android 6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Found answer here

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/316552/#Comment_316552

> Make sure that you are changing the tag.id to google_apis as
>   google_apis_playstore is only available in newer APIs like 24+.

[image]